# huge degrees of freedom for post-hoc tests of lmer model using emmeans

Tags: t-test, lme4-nlme, post-hoc, degrees-of-freedom, lsmeans

I have a trial-wise linear mixed model with a categorial between-subjects factor group (A vs B) and two categorical within-subjects factors itemEmotion (neutral vs. negative) and neuralArea (frontal vs. posterior) and their interactions and random intercepts for each subject (n=52, 26 per group) and item (60 items in total, 30 neutral, 30 negative):

```
LMM <- lmer(neuralActivity ~ group * itemEmotion * neuralArea +
              (1 | subject) + (1| item), data = data)
summary(LMM)
```

Based on a significant group x neuralArea interaction I ran post-hoc tests on the difference between frontal and posterior neuralArea in each group using `emmeans()`:

```
LMM.emmeans = emmeans (LMM, pairwise ~ neuralArea|group, lmer.df = "satterthwaite", 
                       lmerTest.limit=6240)
summary(LMM.emmeans)
```

with those results:

```
$emmeans
group = A:
 neuralArea  emmean      SE  df   lower.CL upper.CL
 anterior    0.00295 0.00133 119  0.0003165  0.00559
 posterior   0.00536 0.00133 119  0.0027233  0.00800

group = B:
 neuralArea  emmean      SE  df   lower.CL upper.CL
 anterior    0.00257 0.00133 119 -0.0000661  0.00521
 posterior   0.01082 0.00133 119  0.0081836  0.01346

Results are averaged over the levels of: itemEmotion 
Degrees-of-freedom method: satterthwaite 
Confidence level used: 0.95 

$contrasts
group = A:
 contrast              estimate      SE   df t.ratio p.value
 anterior - posterior  -0.00241 0.00157 6124  -1.531  0.1258

group = B:
 contrast               estimate      SE   df t.ratio p.value
 anterior - posterior   -0.00825 0.00157 6124  -5.248  <.0001

Results are averaged over the levels of: itemEmotion 
Degrees-of-freedom method: satterthwaite
```

What really confuses me are the 6124 df's for the t-tests as I've never seen such high df's reported. Is such a number possible with only 60 trials and 26 participants per group or is something off here? Note, that in this example I implemented `lmerTest.limit=6240` because otherwise my df's are reported to be INF and z-tests instead of t-tests are computed and that I used satterthwaite's method because the computation is much faster than with Kennward-Roger, but both methods give me the same number for the degrees of freedom in those contrasts.

Also, p-value adjustment for multiple testing does not seem to work with any contrasts that I computed for this model as I get the same p-value and no comment regarding the p-value adjustment in my results outputs for each `p.adjust.methods=` (e.g. "fdr", "bonferroni", "none") command that I've added either into the `emmeans()` or the `summary()` function. The adjustment does actually work using `multcomp::glht()`, but this gives me only z-values instead of t-values and again no df's at all. Or is a z-test actually more appropriate in this case?

However, I'm mainly interested in knowing whether those degrees of freedom of the t-test make sense?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, P value adjustments are done separately for each "by" group, and you have only one comparison in each group, hence no multiplicity of tests, hence no multiplicity adjustments are needed nor done. If you do `summary(LMM.emmeans$contrasts, by = NULL, adjust = "bonf")`, you will see an adjustment for the two comparisons considered as one family of tests.

Second, when you have a within-subjects comparison, the subject effects cancel out because they are on the same subject. That means the degrees of freedom needed to estimate the subject variations do no play a role, and that makes the d.f. for the comparison a lot greater than the d.f. for the means themselves. It will not exceed the number of observations in the dataset, however.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply! Indeed `summary(LMM.emmeans$contrasts, by = NULL, adjust = "bonf")` does finally show an adjustment.

Comment: However, I still don't know whether my dfs are right? You said the dfs should not exceed the observations in the dataset. I would have guessed that I have 30 x 2 (emotion) x 2 (neuralArea) observations per subject, which would be far away from 6425?

Comment: From your code, I guess that you have 6240 observations in the dataset -- right? Look at `nrow(data)`

Comment: Oh, yes you are right. I misunderstood your answer, I thought you meant that it only includes within-subject variability, but of course I still need to count in each subject resulting in 6240 (52x30x2x2) which is indeed also the result for `nrow(data)`. So, I guess my dfs are fine then. Thank you very much!

Comment: Oh wait, but this would be the whole data set and my tests are applied separately in each group resulting in only only half of the data points. Or are still all data points taken into account because its based on the model which takes the whole data into account?

Comment: But it still doesn't sound right, that the data from participants which are not included in the contrast is included in the computation of the degrees of freedom..

Comment: The d.f. are not for the contrast, they are for its SE which is based on pooled variance estimates in a homogeneous model like this one.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your very helpful comments!